# Enzyme test fails TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have implemented testing a canvas file using Jest and enzyme, but whenever I am running test it is saying
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

So here is my test code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { shallow } from "enzyme"
import { ReferenceImageCanvas } from "./../index"

describe("<ReferenceImageCanvas />", () => {
  const props = {
    dispatch: jest.fn(),
    canvasID: "canvas-1",
    reset: true,
    scale: 1,
    imgSrc: ""
  }

  it("renders when loading true", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ReferenceImageCanvas {...props} />)
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
  })
})
```

While running this npm test I am getting following errors:

```
<ReferenceImageCanvas /> › renders when loading true

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

      32 |     const imageSrc = this.props.imgSrc
      33 |     const canvas = document.getElementById(this.state.canvasId)
    > 34 |     const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
         |                        ^
      35 |     const baseImage = new Image()
      36 |     baseImage.src = imageSrc
      37 |     this.setState({

      at ReferenceImageCanvas.componentDidMount (src/canvas/referenceImageCanvas/index.js:34:24)
      at Object.it (src/canvas/referenceImageCanvas/__test__/index.test.js:16:21)
```

Though my react program is running fine.

Is this testing error or I am doing something wrong cant understand

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.canvasId`?

Comment: This is the canvas id which is equal to "canvas-1"

Comment: You have `canvasID` in props but `canvasId` in state. is this intentional?

Comment: Add a `console.log(document)` after line 32 and check if canvas-1 exists. Also please post code of ReferenceImageCanvas

Comment: Actually we are getting this canvasID from parent component which is set to "canvas-1" and in ReferenceImageCanvas component we are assigning this props to state canvasId